# argument type mismatch with sum-function

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink, criteria-api

I'm getting "argument type mismatch" with the sum-function mapping to a non-managed jpa entity.

The query:

```
final Path<String> departmentPath = root.get(SomeEntity_.department);
final Path<Status> statusPath = root.get(SomeEntity_.status);

final Predicate statusActivePred = cb.equal(statusPath, Status.ACTIVE);
final Expression<Integer> activeExp = cb.<Integer> selectCase().when(statusActivePred, Integer.valueOf(1)).otherwise(Integer.valueOf(0));
final Expression<Integer> sumActiveExp = cb.sum(activeExp );

query.select(cb.construct(SomeInfo.class, departmentPath, sumActiveExp));
...
```

The mapping-class:

```
public class SomeInfo
{
  private final String department;

  private final Integer someCount;

  public SomeInfo(final String department)
  {
    super();
    this.department= department;
  }

  public SomeInfo(final String department, final Integer someCount)
  {
    super();
    this.department= department;
    this.someCount = someCount;
  }
...
```

The exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.PrivilegedAccessHelper.invokeConstructor(PrivilegedAccessHelper.java:389)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQueryResult.buildResult(ReportQueryResult.java:121)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQueryResult.<init>(ReportQueryResult.java:78)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQuery.buildObject(ReportQuery.java:593)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQuery.buildObjects(ReportQuery.java:644)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ReportQuery.java:847)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:852)
```

Something like this bellow works, but not the expression with the sum-function

```
query.select(cb.construct(SomeInfo.class, departmentPath));
```

Any hints?

Comment: Try using Object as the type of SomeInfo.someCount, and inspect the type of the object. My guess is that the sum is returned as a Long, and not an Integer.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Turned out to be a BigDecimal for some reason I couldn't figure out yet. The big question now: Is my code or EclipseLink wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect it to return `Long`, because that is consistent with JPQL. In JPA 2.0 specification SUM function is described as follows:

> SUM returns Long when applied to state fields of integral types (other
>   than BigInteger); Double when applied to state fields of floating
>   point types; BigInteger when applied to state fields of type
>   BigInteger; and BigDecimal when applied to state fields of type
>   BigDecimal.

Also Hibernate seems to works that way and return type is `Long`.

If `Long` is preferred, return type can be affected also with EclipseLink. That can be done via [CriteriaBuilder.sumAsLong](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#sumAsLong%28javax.persistence.criteria.Expression%29):

```
final Expression<Long> sumActiveExp = cb.sumAsLong(activeExp);
```

Comment: cb.sumAsLong is what I eventually used.